# Spring security remember me cause 404

Tags: spring, spring-security, http-status-code-404, remember-me

I am trying to use remember me, that seems to be very simple but I get a 404 when I launch the application (404 not found).

My jsp looks like that :

```
<form class="login" name='loginForm' action="<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check' />" method='POST'>
            <input id="j_username" name="j_username" type="text" placeholder="Username" />
            <input id="j_password" name="j_password" type="password" placeholder="Password" />
            <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Sign In" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" />
            <div class="remember-forgot">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="_spring_security_remember_me" />
                                Remember Me
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 forgot-pass-content">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="forgot-pass">Forgot Password</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
```

and My spring security xml :

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" /> 
    <intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_check" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <form-login 
        login-page="/login"
        login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
        default-target-url="/admin"
        username-parameter="j_username"
        password-parameter="j_password"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error" ></form-login>
    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
    <csrf disabled="true"/>
    <remember-me key="myAppKey" />
</http>

    <beans:bean id="CustomAuthenticationProvider" class="com.meltum.springconfiguration.CustomAuthenticationProvider" />

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider ref="CustomAuthenticationProvider" />
     </authentication-manager>
```

Does anybody know how to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to name remember me checkbox same as in the spring security configuration -"remember_me". Or you can use default value "_spring_security_remember_me" with just "key" property in configuration.

Comment: thank you for reply, i updated my jsp with the actual name of the checkbox, You're right the name was not correct. but I corrected and it's not working too

Comment: For default value you don't need remember-me-parameter. If this is persistent approach then you miss "data-source-ref" parameter. If not you just need  <remember-me key="myAppKey"/> and that's it, optionaly you can add validity seconds parameter

Comment: This is one very good guide IMO http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-remember-me-example/

Comment: Yes it's what i did but not working. You can see my post (updated with the default value). I'm going to see your link now